# How to generate __gm_id for a new shape

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have saved a rectangle bounds in the database and I'm able to show the rectangle on the map.

Below is the code for showing rectangle on a map.

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({ 
bounds: bounds,
fillColor: "#FF0000",
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
clickable: true
});

rectangle.setMap(map);
```

While creating a new shape using drawingmanager, I am able to get unique **__gm_id** for each shape.

But when create a shape without drawingmanager, I'm not getting this unique id. How do i generate a unique id for already saved shape without using drawing manager?

Comment: you should thank Andrew for editing your post and removing the term "urgent". See: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do? Give an example? Do you just need a reference to the created rectangle? What exactly is `__gm_id`? To me, `__gm_id` sounds like an internal, "private" variable name and shouldn't be used directly. I heard such names can change without warning when new API versions are released and then what works today will break unexpectedly .